# Serve a jar file from within a war file (as a resource)

Tags: java, web-applications, jar, war

I have a web app: MyApp.war, inside it, I have a jar file: `WEB-INF/lib/PublicJar.jar`

- I want client applications to be able to download that jar like a web resource.
  e.g `http://theserver.com/myapp/jars/PublicJar.jar`
- I want the web application to be able to compute the hashcode of the jar file to
  see if it has changed, so clients know if it needs to reload it.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resources inside `WEB-INF` cannot be served directly to the client. If you want to do that, you need to write a servlet/controller to extract it as a `ServletContext` resource and feed it to the http response.

Is `PublicJar.jar` also used by your application itself? Could you not move it out of `WEB-INF`, or maybe bundle two copies of it in the WAR, one under `WEB-INF` (for internal application use), and one for downloading?

Comment: PublicJar.jar is used by the application, as it loads resources out if it (via spring's resource loader classpath:public/resource.xml).  Actually PublicJar.jar contains only resources - its just a jar to keep them all together as self contained unit.

Comment: In that case, move the jar out of WEB-INF, Spring will still be able to load using a ServletContextResource. Once out of WEB-INF, clients will be able to access it directly.

Comment: Thanks!  The spring resource loader totally helped.  I went with the servlet approach because I already use HttpInvoker for the clients so I added a service method: byte[] readPublicJar() - quick + dirty.  If PublicJar ever gets big, i'll have to move it to the servlet context rather than read it in from the servlet.